# Create new Android project to replace old one but able to submit to Google Play

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, google-play

I have migrated an old project of mine from eclipse to android studio (Ubuntu) with some limited success.

I now want to create a new project in Android studio, dragging in classes and refactoring them as I go.

Then I will want to submit my new Android studio project to the app store as and upgrade to my old project using the correct signing key.

My question is what do I have to keep the same in the new project as the old project so that I can do this?

Comment: If I got it right, you just need to compile with the same key from your keystore, at export time. Of course you need to increase the the version number in your `manifest` before uploading it, just like a regular update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the following unchanged:

1. Your keystore file, alias name and password.
2. Your app's package name.

Don't forget to update your version code to the newer one.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

If I got this right, you just need to compile with the same key from your keystore, at export time. Of course you need to increase the version number in your manifest before uploading it, just like a regular update.

If you need more information, about how to sign an app with android studio look at the [google developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#overview)